# Source .tex invisible

Tags: editors, texshop, macos

I have a problem with TeXshop (on Sierra). When I click on a `.tex`-file it compiles it to PDF but I cannot see (and thus modify) the source window. Any idea why ?

Comment: do you see the window when you press CMD + TAB?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](//tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: @naphaneal Cmd-Tab switches between applications in the Mac, not between windows.  Cmd-1 should switch to the source window (but see my answer for why the source window may not exist.)

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause of this behaviour is that you have set TeXShop to be used with an external editor, so TeXShop displays only the preview window, and assumes you are editing the source somewhere else. The source window is therefore unavailable.

To solve this, go to the TeXShop Preferences and in the On Startup part of the panel, make sure the Configure For External Editor is not checked.  You will need to restart TeXShop to have the setting take effect.

[image: preference pane]